# Drawing a Multi Line Chart from nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a simple multi line chart from nested data. I'm facing no javascript errors but there is no chart drawn. Even the x-Axis is missing but I cannot find the reason why.
I have made an example here with only one user, the goal would be to have a multitude of users.

http://blockbuilder.org/con-ssc/56b1f647f43b03e8ad5fc923a551b0ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. I can't make any sense out of your `parseTime` function.  You parse it, then format it to a string, then parse it again, why?
2. Your x-axis doesn't show because your SVG needs to be sized to the full width/height, not width/height minus margins.
3. Your data is not-sorted by the x-axis variable.
4. Your y scale domain is not being properly set.

Fixing all these problems results in [this here](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/eeff090ca1368ab5403b369ba8bc02fc).

Comment: Thank you very much, if only had seen this earlier :D